# Find a parametrization of a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^4$ given by the equation $x+y+z+at=b$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, parametric, parametrization

Find a parametrization of the hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^4$ given by the equation $x+y+z+at=b$ where $a,b$ are real numbers.

I'm not sure about my answer:

$$y
\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\ 
1\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix} + x
\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\ 
0\\ 
1\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix} +t 
\begin{pmatrix}
-a\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix} + b
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Is this correct?

Thanks!

Comment: $$p
\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\ 
1\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix} + q
\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\ 
0\\ 
1\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix} +r 
\begin{pmatrix}
-a\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix} +
\begin{pmatrix}
b\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$$
Is this correct ? @Bye_World

Comment: Naa, right.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your parametrization is correct.**

Just to make my answer a little more substantial, I'll tell you that I'd tweak your answer a bit.  $(1)$ I'd *name* the parameterization.  $(2)$ I'd introduce *new* variable names for the parameters.  And $(3)$ I'd specify the values that those new variables can take.  So I'd write the answer as

$$\vec v(p,q,r) = \pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z \\ t} =  p
\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\ 
1\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix} + q
\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\ 
0\\ 
1\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix} +r 
\begin{pmatrix}
-a\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix} + 
\begin{pmatrix}
b\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix},\quad p,q,r\in \Bbb R$$

If you can explain why you're not confident about your solution in the comments below, I'll attempt to assuage your doubts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and we went over the subject one last time in class, I understood.